# How do i retrieve data from YTD to last sunday?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to make an SQL code so it automatically extracts data from the current year and until last sunday.. The first part was fairly easy, but I'm struggling with dynamically adding last sunday..

Have read through 4-5 other threads on here, but have not been able to get anything from them, as the code just returns and error or the wrong results

I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0.16 if that is of any help :)

```
"my.column" between DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() ,'%Y-01-01') AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Store Last Sunday in variable and use it

```
 DECLARE @CurrentWeekday INT = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
 DECLARE @LastSunday DATETIME = DATEADD(day, -1 * (( @CurrentWeekday % 7) -1), GETDATE())

 BETWEEN convert(datetime,'01-01-'+convert(varchar(10),datepart (year,getdate()))) and 
 @LastSunday
```

Comment: It is not possible for me to use DECLARE functions, so was hoping I could get this weeks sunday and subtract 1 week from it rather simply.. Is that not possible?

Comment: ok if you cannont declare than simply paste code instead of variable :)   

BETWEEN convert(datetime,'01-01-'+convert(varchar(10),datepart (year,getdate()))) and  convert( datetime,DATEADD(day, -1 * (( DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) -1), GETDATE()))

Comment: Hi Tahreem, thanks for your help.. Unfortunately these suggestions give me errors.. So I'm looking for something to identify sunday in this week and ideally subtract with 1 week

Comment: Hi , i understand you need last sunday .you can try below

BETWEEN convert(datetime,'01-01-'+convert(varchar(10),datepart (year,getdate()))) and DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,1,GETDATE()), -8)